I am receiving this error code when starting the R studio from the App
R Session Startup Failure Report
RStudio Version
RStudio 2022.07.0+548 "Spotted Wakerobin " (34ea3031, 2022-07-06) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.07.0+548 Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Electron/19.0.4 Safari/537.36
Error message
[No error available]
Process Output
The R session exited with code 1.
Error output:
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/rsession
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: cannot load 'libssl.1.1.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: cannot load 'libssl.1.1.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)


Standard output:
[No output emitted]

Logs
Log File
[No logs available]

I tried resolving by deleting .Rprofile or previously installed R versions. Still does not work.

Try updating to the latest version of RStudio. Your version is quite old and that may be the reason for your error.
